# java fx aligment issue with text labels and textfields

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, scenebuilder

Hi everybody I have a problem with javaFX. I have developed a screen with a fixed widht and height. On my computer looks everything ok,however, in another bigger screen the text labels are cut and also text fields .I am working on windows 8 and using jdk 8. has anybody idea why is this scaling issue? and how to fix it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please post code. Which layout pane are you using?

Comment: I didnt use css, I just created the view with scenebuilder. I added labels and textfields, very simple. Like I said, on my computer everything look ok and with another resolution labels are cut.No sense to show code because it is fxml code generated by scenebuilder